# I can't wy icon svg is not visible

Tags: svg, impresspages

It's my first time hier.

I'm discover the CMS impresspage and I'm very glad with.

I'm install the program, all is good, expect one. The little image on admin are not visible. You can see [All icon.svg are strang](http://www.slorimier.ch/cloud/public.php?service=files&t=f72601e1e46f39d5540cab02f4b4b619)

I tried on Firefox 28 and Chrome 34

You can see on http://slorimier.ch/cms/ImpressPages/admin, demo and demo123

I have made all icon as png, but is for me difficult to understand how make the change.

If someone can me help, I'm glad.

Thanks all.

Stéphane

Comment: The images are all PNGs now, and seem to be showing up fine. Did you fix your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I found the the solution there : http://www.w3.org/services/svg-server/

The htaccess fix did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Those images work on Firefox and Chrome. The only reason I could think of is failed file upload to the server. Try to reupload "Ip" directory to the server once again.